# Update only changed items in observableArray when fetching from datasource

Tags: knockout.js, polling, knockout-2.0

**What i'm doing**: Polling remote datesource every 30 seconds for data.
I then do `self.MyCollection(newData);`.

**My Problem**: since i might have filtered the array or expanded a specific array item in the   UI, i don't want it to reset every 30 seconds.

I only want to update and re-render my observableArray when the items actually change.

Anyone know how to avoid reseting the ui when the underlying observableArray changes - or - how to avoid that the whole observableArray changes when only 1 or less underlying item changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by simple iterating the items in the observableArray and changed the values (which were observables themselves). This updated just the `<li>` in the list, and not the whole `<ul>`.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what exactly you want to do, but the official knockoutjs documentation describes a similar problem: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

On section `Customizing object updating using “update”` :

> You can also customize how an object is updated by specifying an
>   update callback. It will receive the object it is trying to update and
>   an options object which is identical to the one used by the create
>   callback.

Comment: I have not had the time to test this solution. I will have to return and do this on my free time, if anyone else have tried this and says it work i will accept the answer. I abandoned the idea of update the underlying observableArray while the UI is being used.